# Grouping partial table data on SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table data as below. In this scenario, an employee can have either 1 or 0 or (1 and 0) but never employee exists with combination of multiple 1 and multiple 0.

**Employee**    **Status**

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th> Employee</th>
  <th> Status </th>
   <tr>
  <tr>
  <td>abc </td>
  <td> 1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>abc </td>
  <td> 1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>PQR </td>
  <td> 1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>XYZ </td>
  <td> 0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Below is what is expected from the output.

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th> Employee</th>
  <th> Status </th>
   <tr>
    <tr>
  <td>abc </td>
  <td> $</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>PQR </td>
  <td> yes</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>XYZ </td>
  <td> no</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That means, if there are duplicate records then status should be $, if 1 then yes and if 0 then No.

Thank you in advance for helping on this

What I have tried:

```
;with CTEE (RowNumber, EmployeeName, [Status]) As 
(select a.RowNumber,
        a.EmployeeName, 
        case when a.rowNumber > 1 then '' 
             when a.rowNumber = 1 and Working = 0 then 'N' 
             else 'Y' end as [Status] 
 from (select Row_Number() over(Partition by EmployeeName order by EmployeeName) as [RowNumber],
       EmployeeName, 
       [Status] 
       from [Table] 
       group by EmployeeName, [Status] ) a ) 

select EmployeeName, [Status] 
from CTEE c1 
where (RowNumber = 1 
and EmployeeName not in 
       (select EmployeeName 
        from CTEE where EmployeeName = c1.EmployeeName and [Status] = '')) or RowNumber =2
```

Comment: ';with CTEE (RowNumber, EmployeeName, [Status]) 
As
(select a.RowNumber,a.EmployeeName, case when a.rowNumber > 1 then '*' 
      when a.rowNumber = 1 and Working = 0 then 'N'
         else 'Y' end as [Status] 
from 
(
select Row_Number() over(Partition by EmployeeName order by EmployeeName) as [RowNumber],EmployeeName, [Status]
 from [Table]
group by EmployeeName, [Status]
) a

)
select EmployeeName, [Status] from CTEE c1
where (RowNumber = 1 and EmployeeName not in 
(select EmployeeName from CTEE where EmployeeName = c1.EmployeeName and [Status] = '*')) or RowNumber =2'

Comment: add your query to the **question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of approaches to this, here is one that uses derived tables to get the `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT T.Employee,
       CASE WHEN Cnt > 1 THEN '$'
            WHEN Cnt = 1 AND Status = 1 THEN 'yes'
            ELSE 'no' END as 'Status'

FROM        (SELECT DISTINCT Employee, Status
             FROM Table) T
INNER JOIN  (SELECT COUNT(STATUS) as 'Cnt', Employee
             FROM Table
             GROUP BY Employee) T2 on T2.Employee = T.Employee
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron for replying, it does the job and I had done a kind of similar approach... With the query you have given it gives the duplicate record for the status $, Can this be avoided.

Comment: I got it ... Thank you

Comment: @VinayakShindagi The `DISTINCT` select on the first inner query should have handled that... On another note, welcome to SO.  For a first question, yours was good, but in future questions be sure to post what you've tried to far.  Even if it's completely wrong, the question will be better received.  And of course, upvote/mark correct answers. ;)

Comment: I did post it in other comment above, but it was not formatted properly. yup taken your advice

Comment: @VinayakShindagi Right on, thanks.  Moved it to the question for formatting.  Yeah your approach was pretty similar.  And it shows that you know what you're doing and you're not just asking for the answer to a homework question.